# How sort method works internally in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, methods

I know for some of you it may be a silly question, but it is a confusion for me. how it works without assigning to a variable and how it's updated value is usable.

This code print sorted list

## Python code

```
data=[23,11,32,89,52,99]
data.sort()
print(data)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in the same way as this code:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def modify(self):
        self.value += 1

data = Thing(5)
print(data.value)  # prints '5'

data.modify()
print(data.value)  # prints '6'
```

Basically, it modifies the *internal* state of the object. The list object stores its values in some region of memory (that is, in some internal variable), and the `sort` method messes with this *internal* variable in such a way that the list's values are sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable, `data`, is a list. A list has a method called `sort`, which sorts the list and updates those values. You can see all methods by entering `dir(data)` or even directly on the data type `dir(list)`.

This is different than the function `sorted()`, which sorts the list and returns the sorted value, but does not update the original list.

```
data=[23,11,32,89,52,99]
print(sorted(data))  # Returns sorted list
print(data)  # Original is not modified
data.sort()  # Modifies original
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `list.sort()` method modifies the list **in-place**. Other method like `sorted()` will not modify the list. For example:

```
data=[23,11,32,89,52,99]
sorted(data)
print(data)

Out:
[23, 11, 32, 89, 52, 99]
```

Assigned:

```
data=[23,11,32,89,52,99]
data = sorted(data)
print(data)

Out:
[11, 23, 32, 52, 89, 99]
```

So it depends on how the method is structured. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

List is an object

```
class list(object):
    """
    list() -> new empty list
    list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
    """
    def append(self, p_object): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end """
        pass
    def sort(self, key=None, reverse=False): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ L.sort(key=None, reverse=False) -> None -- stable sort *IN PLACE* """
        pass
```